# Dúvida com parâmetro

Tags: python, django

Estou assistindo um [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uboulcaJzKk&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQSEMN5PXvEWuD2gEWVngCZ&index=15) de python mas não entendi uma coisa.

Tenho o arquivo utils.py

```
def code_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def create_shortcut(instance, size = 6):
    new_code = code_generator(size = size)
    Klass = instance.__class__
    qs_exists = Klass.objects.filter(shortcode=new_code).exists()
    if qs_exists:
        return create_shortcut(size = size)
    return new_code
```

Arquivo model.py

```
def save(self, *args, **kargs):
   if self.shortcode is None or self.shortcode == "":
       self.shortcode = create_shortcut(self)
   super(KirrURL, self).save(*args, **kargs)
```

No arquivo model.py é feito a chamada `create_shortcut(self)` o que entendi, que é passado a própria classe, e não foi informado o parâmetro `size` que é default 6.

Porém, aqui no utils.py:

```
 if qs_exists:
    return create_shortcut(size = size)
```

No trecho acima não teria que ser `return create_shortcut(instance, size = size)`? Porque não foi passado o parâmetro `instance` novamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso - não vi o vídeo com áudio, mas sim, esse código está errado.O parâmetro `instance` é obrigatório e não é passado - talvez tenha sido um exemplo de código criaod ao vivo enquanto o vídeo foi feito, e portanto, sujeito a erros.

O que acontece éque como a expressão com erro está dentro de um "if" pode ser que nos casos que ele tenha testado ao vivo nunca tenha rodado, e aí o erro não apareceu.

Comment: Mudei o código para passar naquela condição e deu o erro: create_shortcut() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'. Obrigado, tinha ficado bem confuso pela falta do argumento, por causa do "self" que não precisa informar, achei que nesse caso seria algo do tipo